# Why is the || operator not triggered here?

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
    int precision = 10;
    int choice;

    //Title and Menu
    cout << endl << "==============" << endl << " TRIGONOMETRY " << endl << "==============";
    cout << endl << "Current Precision: " << precision;
    cout << endl << endl << "Select:";
    cout << endl << "1. Calculate Cos and Sin";
    cout << endl << "8. Change Precision";
    cout << endl << "9. Exit";

    while (true)
    {
        //User Prompt
        cout << endl << endl << "Please enter your choice. => ";
        cin >> choice;
        
        if (choice != 1 || choice != 8 || choice != 9)
            {
                cout << endl <<  "Please enter a value between 1, 8 and 9.";
            }  

        if (choice == 8)
            {
                cout << endl << "Current Precision: " << precision;
                cout << endl << "Please enter your desired precision => ";
                cin >> precision;
                cout << endl << "Precision has been set to " << precision;
            }

        if (choice == 9)
            {
                break;
            }
    }   
}
```

The idea is that if the user inputs something other than 1, 8 or 9 the program will print the line, but when I supposedly fulfilled the condition by inputting 4, 5, etc., the program jumps back to the main function without printing the line. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
I have since edited the condition for the first if loop to (choice != 1 && choice != 8 && choice != 9), but another problem now is that the program doesn't print the line when I input any non-1, 8, 9 numbers. I omitted the if loop for (choice == 1) cause it's too long and it might hinder reading.

Comment: Think about the logic - are you sure `||` is the right choice? ;)

Comment: Which is pretty strange cause I initially went with &&, but it gave me the same results as || did.

Comment: No it didn't :P

Comment: What is `choice`'s data type? I suspect that it's a `char`, so even after fixing the broken boolean logic, it still will not do what you want it to do.

Comment: Another way of saying _"something other than 1, 8 or 9"_ is "something that is not 1, and is not 8, and is not 9"

Comment: @SamVarshavchik it's actually int, and what is strange is that I have other if loops with the conditions being choice == 1, choice == 8 and choice == 9, and they all work fine except for this one.

Comment: In that case the problem is only the broken boolean logic.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Hm, strange. Do you have any clue as to why that one particular loop might not work? I tried implementing the loop in a clean file and it works just fine.

Comment: Well, that suggests the difference is not the `if` statement itself, but something else, some other related code that's not shown, and you can't really expect anyone to figure out something about some code that's not even shown. What you need to do is follow stackoverflow.com's instructions for creating a [mre], and then [edit] your question accordingly. Until you do that it's unlikely anyone will be able to tell you the answer.

Comment: If you are absolutely sure that && didn't work: Maybe - since there is no flush at the end (endl is *before* text), the code buffers the output, then goes into an infinite loop somewhere else, and this is not displayed. Just guessing.

Comment: @Cem I have edited the question with a minimal reproducible example, and I tried adding an endl behind the text as well but it didn't work. The problem probably isn't that. Thanks for the answer anyway!

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thank you kind sir. I have edited the question with the full code. Please take a look at it if you don't mind. Thanks.

Comment: *"I omitted the if loop for (choice == 1) cause it's too long and it might hinder reading."* -- that's a good thought (except an `if` statement is not a loop), but consider this: you are presenting an *example*, not your actual code. How long is `if ( choice == 1) { /* Do stuff */ }`? Along similar lines, how would it hurt this example if you changed the handling for case 8 to `if ( choice == 8) { /* Do stuff */ }`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the And operator (`&&`) to achieve the result that you want, try this:

```
if (choice != 1 && choice != 8 && choice != 9)
   {
      cout << endl << "Please enter a valid choice between 1, 8 and 9.";
   }
```

The reason why it didn't work with the Or operator (`||`) is because that for each number among 1, 8 or 9, your condition will always remains as true.
(For example:
If choice = 1, choice != 1 might return false but choice != 8 will return true).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It fixed the loop, but I have another problem where the loop just doesn't trigger at all when the other loops do. I have edited my question and code accordingly. Would you mind taking a look at that? Thanks again.

Comment: Your code doesn't contain the fixed if statement with the correct boolean logic, are you sure you have updated it ?

Comment: Yes I have. I posted the pre-change code in case my original question wouldn't make sense to others reading it.

Comment: @NGZHISHUEN — don’t edit your code to ask a different question. Post a new question.